# Video stream from client to server in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm currently developing an application to stream video feed from client to server in NodeJS. The server side code is as shown below

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const auth = require('./routes/auth')
const video = require('./routes/videoproc')(io)


const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use("/users", auth)
app.use("/exam", video);


server.listen(3000)
```

**videoproc.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const video = express.Router()
const ss = require('socket.io-stream')
const fs  = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (io) => {
    video.post('/video', (req, res) => {
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            ss(socket).on('video', (stream, data) => {
                const fileName = path.basename('test')
                stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName))
            })
        })
    })
    return video
}
```

This is the **client side code**

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var fs = require('fs')
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/exam/video/');
var stream = ss.createStream();
var filename = './test.webm';
 
ss(socket).emit('video', stream, {name: filename});
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
```

As a test I've send a video feed to the server but the file is not being stored, some help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server you should:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
// app.use("/users", auth)
app.use("/exam", video);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('CONNECTED');
    ss(socket).on('video', (stream, data) => {
        console.log('RECEIVED');
        const fileName = path.basename('test')
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName))
    })
})
server.listen(3000)
```

and Client: param in a connect function is just "http://localhost:3000/", exclude route

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');
var stream = ss.createStream();
var filename = './test.webm';
 
ss(socket).emit('video', stream, {name: filename});
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
```

At client: connect to a domain, not route:
[ref](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-a-different-domain)

At server: you placed io.on on a route, io.on is just listen when you call the route. if you want run when server starting, you should place io.on outside the route

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I stream from a webcam will the file be saved as chunks?

Comment: What protocol does the webcam use when stream? How the file is saved depends on the format you want to save it in. You can control this

Comment: And if the answer above can solve your question, please give it a green tick

Comment: "client side" code throws this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined" and I cannot require fs because  ReferenceError: require is not defined".  That is not client side, is just a nodejs client (server)